# Windows Python v. Linux Python: "from module import *" is not importing on Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-2.7, python-import

Having what I think is an unusual problem. I have a Python script `script1.py` defining `class BaseClass(dict)`, and another script defining `class ChildClass(BaseClass)`.

`ChildClass` import the first script with `from script1 import *`, however when trying to run `ChildClass` I get `NameError: name 'BaseClass' is not defined`.

```
# script1.py
...
class BaseClass(dict):
    def __init__(self, params):
        pass
...

# ChildClass.py
from script1 import *

class ChildClass(BaseClass):
...
```

The exact same scripts run fine on my home machine (Ubuntu 15.04), but my work machine (Windows 7 Pro) I'm getting the aforementioned NameError.

I've checked in the python environment, and it is indeed finding the `script1.py` file, but not actually importing any of the functions inside.

```
>>> from script1 import *
>>> BaseClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'BaseClass' is not defined'
```

I'm imagining the problem is the difference between Windows Python and Linux Python, but I've never had this kind of problem before. Any insight is welcome.

Comment: You have some other script named `script1` in one of the folders in your `sys.path`, and it does not include a `BaseClass`. Try `import script1; print script1.__file__`

Comment: Do `import script1` and then print `script1.__file__` and see where it's finding the module.

Comment: @kindall @Brenbarn Doing so results in `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__`.  I know it's reading script1, though, because trying to enter `import randomstringao` raises an ImportError.

Comment: What's the actual name of this module? Because the error you're getting usually indicates a built-in module.

Comment: Are you sure both computers are using Python 2? Python 2 and 3 have somewhat different relative import rules, and [it looks like you're getting the built-in `parser` module on one machine](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html).

Comment: Mother of God. Yes, script1 shares a name with a built-in module. I wasn't thinking about the built-in module at all because the script1 I am using was written by another team member. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: And off the top of my head I can't say what Python version I have on my home machine but it's probably 3.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out (hypothetically named) `script1` shares a name with a built-in Python module. It looks like the error wasn't occurring on my home machine because I'm running Python 3 there and 2 on my work machine.

To solve this, I've simply re-named `script1`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, should have specified. `script1` is just a placeholder. It's actually `parser`.